# display two items data in Ms Chart Control VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, mschart

I'm new to MS Chart control. I want to display sql conditional result in chart control. This is my codes

Dim strQry As String = "SELECT format(sDate, 'MMMM-YYYY') AS [Month], iCode as [Item], Sum(iQty) AS [Total Qty] FROM Sales WHERE iCode ='DJ100106' OR iCode='DJ100107' GROUP BY format(sDate, 'MMMM-YYYY'), icode ORDER BY cDate(format(sDate, 'MMMM-YYYY'))"

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQry, Conn)

    da.Fill(dt)
    Chart1.Series(0).Color = Color.YellowGreen
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Month"
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Total Qty"
    Chart1.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    Chart1.DataSource = dt
```

For one condition in WHERE clause, chart control displays the bars correctly. If I add more condition such as "OR iCode = 'DJ100107'", chart control displays inappropriate bars and values in X axis.

I want to compare these two items (DJ100106 and DJ100107) sold in every month in chart. Grid control displays the exact result what I want. But the chart control doesn't. (As shown in the attached image). I am using VB.Net 2012, MS Access Database 2007
Can anyone help me how to solve this?
Thank you
[image: Two Series]

Comment: You want to add a new series to the chart,  Correct?  if so you will find it much simpler to do a separate query for each iCode condition and attach those result sets to a new series.  It may not be the most efficient but it's simple

Comment: Thanks Hursey. I found a solution by adjusting the interval (ChatAreas->Axes->Interval=1) & I able to get the result as I want (as shown in the updated image). But it shows the two items in same color. Could you please let me know how to change the colors for each item?